# How to read a php file, behind "Editable"

Tags: javascript, php

I use "Editable" to "inline edit" my table. When i save my changes it's posted to a php file. The php file is then updating my db.

My problem is that the php script need some error checking.
I need to somehow echo or alert a variable to see what it contains.
But if i echo or alert my variable, it never shows.
I cannot use "xDebug" because i use an external server?!

Is there a way?

Comment: provide your code and more information

Comment: Why can't you use firebug? Firebug has nothing to do with the server (external or not).... it runs in the browser

Comment: @MarkBaker Sorry, "Xdebug"!

Comment: $niyou What do you need more code for? Do you know editable? It's a javascript popup, you never leaves the page. I guess that's why i can't read or se no alert from the php file that is triggered.

Comment: What do you mean... editable? X-editable? bootstrap-editable? Jeditable? HTML contenteditable? Show some code

Comment: $rjdown I can't figure out why you need my code. See answear below!

Comment: @d00rman before your edited you had firebug in your question, that's why we wanted to see your code, because you said it wasn't working! You better read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use firebug, or actually most browsers built in developer tools, to check the XHR information being sent and received.

If you make your server side script send a response back (just with echo), youll be able to see the response content in the XHR information. You can use this for checking variable contents or reporting stages etc.

Alternatively, if the php script is failing completely, youll be able to see in the log files on the server.

for example, if you use chrome:

- click developer tools
- click network
- click one of the information lines
- click response

in there youll see everything that came back

[image]